# Stack Exchange site for discussing international standards

Tags: feature-request, site-proposal

I'm interesting is discussing and asking questions relating to various international and national standards. Is there currently, or is there any plan to create, a Stack Exchange site for standards?

**Defined**

Standards are conventions, whether formalised or not, for interoperation in trade, technology and other areas of human activity involving multiple people across heterogeneous environments.

Most people have heard of international standards such as the ISO 9001 Quality Assurance standard, or ISO 3166 Country and Subdivision codes. These are examples of standards published by ISO, the International Organisation for Standardisation.

Many other organisations, both public and private, also publish standards, such as the IEEE (Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers), the W3C (World Wide Web Consortium), and so forth.

In addition, most countries have national standards organisations, such as Standards Australia which publishes Australian national standards, and so on.

**Relevance**

Standards are an important part of life in technology, trade, commerce, finance, and many other areas of human activity.

The purpose of a relevant Stack Exchange community would be for members to ask questions about the existence, meaning, interpretation and implementation of specific standards which can then be answered by experts on those standards.

I believe this would be an extremely useful resource and lends itself well to the Stack Exchange community-rated question and answer format.

Comment: [area51.se]‍‍‍‍

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but this proposal makes no sense to me. Why try to build a community form around standards, as opposed to the respective fields where they are actually used? If I have a question about a standard published by the W3C, for example, it's likely to be on topic on Stack Overflow or Webmasters.SE.

Comment: Hi Pëkka. The answer is that some standards have many uses. For example, let's say I had a question about ISO 3166 (the definition of Countries and Subdivisions), or let's say I had a question about how trade tariff numbers are defined and who defines them. While some standards have obvious, specific implementations, e.g. the W3C's standards are all about the web, others are much more generic.

Comment: @MarkyMark: It's so rare in my experience to find someone who seems to be as passionate about metrology as I am. You, my good fellow, are a beautiful person! ^-^

Answer (score 2):

I've created a question / proposal on Area51 as recommended by michaelb958 and Pëkka.

[International and National Standards](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13836/international-and-national-standards)

Comment: Thank you. :) I appreciate that. I'm going to go post a question there now. ^_^

Comment: Aaaand apparently it hadn't been accepted because I can't find it, and the post you linked to doesn't contain a link to any A51 site/page either, so... :/