# Best site to ask about metrology?

Tags: discussion, support, site-recommendation

I want to ask a question having to do with international measurement standards, but there doesn't seem to be a site—either full-on or even just in Area 51—that fits this topic.

The closest ones full-fledged sites that I could find was

- English Language & Usage,
- History of Science and Mathematics, and
- Linguistics.

However,

- EL&U is more about usage (go figure), and specifically English, so it doesn't entirely fit the topic;
- HS&M might work, but that still seems to be a bit of a stretch; and
- Linguistics, again, **might** work but a) it seems to be closer to EL&U in this regard than to metrology, and so it would likely be a bit too much of a stretch if you ask me.

As stated, I also looked among the Area 51 proposals and although there was [a proposal for an *International and National Standards* site](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13836/international-and-national-standards), it doesn't seem to have gone anywhere and I can't find any similar or even related site among the ones that have been accepted. I found out about this proposal at [this Meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/226552/297765).

Out of all the Area 51 proposals that have been accepted (I looked at all of them), the ones that seem to best fit this topic are

- Good Practice, and
- Quality Assurance Engineering

However, as with most of the ones above, both of these would be a bit of a stretch, and thus not exactly ideal. Additionally, not only are both still in the *Define* stage of Area 51 development, but the former has only 1 follower and the latter only 6 followers. So I don't see myself as likely to get many quality answers or discussions.

Thoughts, suggestions, or ideas?*

*And, also, *please*: **don't** suggest I make a proposal myself. ...I'm already considering it.

---

***Edit 1***: Some examples of questions I might ask:

- [*What system, if any, is the standard Western "week" a part of?*](https://www.reddit.com/r/Metrology/comments/3lgsyo/what_system_if_any_is_the_standard_western_week_a/)
- [*Do the ISQ and SI share a common system?*](https://www.reddit.com/r/Metrology/comments/3c7d27/do_the_isq_and_si_share_a_common_system/)

Comment: What's the question? Engineering, Aviation, Chemistry, and Electrical Engineering all have fairly knowledgeable user communities. Physics may be of help with foundations of metrology.

Comment: [This.](https://www.reddit.com/r/Metrology/comments/3lgsyo/what_system_if_any_is_the_standard_western_week_a/)

Comment: I also want to ask [this question](https://www.reddit.com/r/Metrology/comments/3c7d27/do_the_isq_and_si_share_a_common_system/) as well.

Comment: Plus, I often do research on metrological concepts, so it'd also just plain be a good thing to be aware of for any possible future questions I may have.

Comment: What do you mean by "system" in this context? Do you mean systems formally recognised by ISO or is your question more on the historical side?

Comment: I mean, for example, like the SI (International System of Units) is a system, the ISQ ([International System of Quantities](http://www.bipm.org/en/publications/si-brochure/section1-2.html)) is a system, the [many different calendres in existence](http://scienceworld.wolfram.com/astronomy/topics/CalendricalSystems.html) are each systems. And, of course, they do not *need* to be from ISO. Lol. There are other standards bodies out there as well. ^_^

Comment: There's ISO calendar, and its weeks are weird =.

Comment: Yeah, haha. Personally, I like ISO 8601 overall, but I frankly dislike the ISO Week Date system.

Comment: Hmm, I *have* seen questions like this asked at Chemistry. You might take a look at there. (Come and ask on our meta or chat first, please)

Comment: @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M: Did you look at those links I posted in the comments above?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a%2F%22#q=metrology+stack suggests [physics.se] has an interest in metrology.

Comment: (Sorry for a late response) On second thought, looking at your questions, I'm not sure if Chemistry will accept them. :/ I believe with a bit of tweaking and witty wording, you can ask them at HS&M. At least the first one for sure.

Comment: @PolyGeo: Definitely a good suggestion. I'll keep that in mind. Thank you.

Comment: @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M: I have no specific questions. Those two I linked to above are just examples. I'm more or less wondering what would be the best site to post on to ask questions about metrology itself, such as its theoretical morphology and such. Obviously, if I wanted to ask about best practice or whatever within a specific field, I'd go to sites about that particular field. :)